# Sentence correction problem. GMAT related

Tags: sentence

**Compared to alligators, crocodiles are better able to tolerate high
   salinity, because, unlike alligators, the glands on crocodiles'
   tongues can expel salt.**

The whole sentence is in question:

A: Salt can be expelled through the glands on crocodiles' tongues and not through those on alligators' tongues; therefore, compared to alligators, crocodiles are more tolerant of high salinity

B: Unlike alligators, crocodiles can expel salt through the glands on their tongues; crocodiles are thus more tolerant of high salinity than are alligators

My question is which one of these is a better replacement. In choice B, do you need the last "are"? Is it redundant? IN choice A, is there anything wrong? What's wrong, if anything, with the word "and" in choice A?

Comment: Many estuarine creatures are more tolerant of high salinity than alligators.  Especially when the alligators are hungry.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is which one of these is a better replacement.

Answer B is the clearest, most direct replacement. The purpose of the sentence is to compare crocodiles and alligators on their tolerance of salinity. Answer A starts with a discussion of salt, whereas answer B starts with a discussion of alligators and crocodiles; ergo B is more direct.

> In choice B, do you need the last "are"? Is it redundant?

The last "are" strikes me as unnecessary, since it's implied. However, I don't know that I'd characterize it as redundant - It's literally saying the same thing twice, whereas I think redundancy typically implies different ways of saying the same thing within a particular context.

> IN choice A, is there anything wrong? What's wrong, if anything, with the word "and" in choice A?

I don't think there's anything inherently wrong, however "but" would be a better choice of conjunction than "and", since it implies exclusion, which is the message this sentence is trying to convey. (Alligators are excluded from the group of creatures which can expel salt through glands on their tongues.)

Answer (score 1):

In context, the "are" near the end of B is redundant.  If you had only the sentence "Crocodiles are thus more tolerant of salinity than are alligators" then I would not recommend removing the second "are" lest someone interpret the sentence as being about crocodiles' toleration of alligators.